# Slip input type value live using javascript

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to live edit a text box value so that the result will be split every two character,
adding a column and starting from some default character.

what i have till now is this code, that obviously doesn't work:

```
 $('#textboxtext').keyup(function (){
            var text = $("#textboxtext").val();
            //$(text).attr('maxlength', '12');
            var splitted = text.match(/.{2}|.{1,2}/g);
            var result = ("B8:27:EB:" + splitted.join(':'));
        });
```

i need the live split and the default character inside the textbox but i really don't know where to start...

Comment: What doesn't work? Your regex is slighlty too complex (`.{1,2}` woudl do) but it should work anyway. What are you doing with the `result` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, it seems like you're trying to create a text box that has some very specific behavior. It looks like it needs to format its value in such a way that it always begins with certain 'prefix' of `B8:27:EB:`, and every subsequent pair of characters is is separated by a `:`. This is actually a very complex behavior and you have to consider a number of different interactions (e.g.  what happens when the user attempts to delete or modify the prefix). I usually try to avoid such complex controls if possible, however here is a quick implementation:

```
$('#textboxtext').keyup(function (e){
     var prefix = "B8:27:EB:", 
         text = $(this).val(),
         splitted, result;
     if (text.indexOf(prefix) == 0)
         text = text.substr(9);
     else if (prefix.indexOf(text) == 0)
         text = "";

     text = text.replace(/:/g, '');
     splitted = text.match(/.{1,2}/g) || [];
     result = prefix + splitted.join(':');

     $(this).val(result);
 });
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/ywUf6/1/)

Type inside the text box and see what happens. Also note, there are all kinds of interaction that this implementation doesn't account for (e.g. right-clicking and pasting into the text box), but it's a start.